# Filter by tags in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, tags

I'm creating a video gallery in wordpress and i need to make a search filter by tags.

The videos will be "wordpress posts" and will open in fancybox.

Just like that: http://molho.tv/ except that in this site the videos doesn't open in fancybox.
(in this case the filters are: ALL, MOTION, FILM, PRINT)

There must be a theme wich i can adapt, or a search plugin that does that.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Artur

Comment: I've visited the link reference you have provided, it seems all the videos are already present in the page and filter is done by javascript by adding some class to those videos searched by class. It's not wordpress filter there.

Comment: Yes, i know it's not wordpress there, what i need is a similar function for wordpress or any other CMS

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/
Or you could code your own solution in PHP/MySQL that searches the tag column of each post in wp_posts, inside video category.